# c#, COM Control not visible through Code

Tags: .net, winforms, com

I am developing a Windows application in C#. One of my requirement is to call a COM Control in the Windows Form, the control is to be added dynamically. Hence I place a button the form, add create an instance of COM Control, add a panel through code then  add the COM Control to panel and then add the panel to the flow layout Panel. So far everything is going as expected. The Code is use to do this :

```
            AxDCControl.AxDCControlCtl axDynamic = new AxDCControl.AxDCControlCtl();

        axDynamic .Size = new Size(486, 88);
        axDynamic .Name = "COM Legacy-" + DateTime.Now.ToString();

        axDynamic .Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        Panel pnl = new Panel();
        pnl.Size = new Size(500, 100);
        pnl.Name = (Convert.ToInt32(lblCtr.Text) + 1).ToString();
        pnl.Dock = DockStyle.None;
        pnl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;


        pnl.Controls.Add(axDynamic );

        flwPnlTLC.Controls.Add(pnl);
        flwPnlTLC.SetFlowBreak(pnl, true);
```

I call the same code in Tree View After Select event, the COM Control is not displayed but I can make out that the control is created since counting the number of controls and displaying their names show the COM Control. In Tree View After Select Event I have placed the same code:

```
AxDCControl.AxDCControlCtl axDynamic = new AxDCControl.AxDCControlCtl();

        axDynamic .Size = new Size(486, 88);
        axDynamic .Name = "COM Legacy-" + DateTime.Now.ToString();

        axDynamic .Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        axDynamic .CreateControl();

        Panel pnl = new Panel();
        pnl.Size = new Size(500, 100);
        pnl.Name = (Convert.ToInt32(lblCtr.Text) + 1).ToString();
        pnl.Dock = DockStyle.None;
        pnl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;


        pnl.Controls.Add(axDynamic );

        flwPnlTLC.Controls.Add(pnl);
        flwPnlTLC.SetFlowBreak(pnl, true);
```

To check that the control is actually loaded in the tree view select event, I have placed a button and added the following:

```
foreach (Control c in flwPnlTLC.Controls)
        {
            label6.Text = label6.Text + Environment.NewLine + c.Name + ":" + c.Parent.Name;

            foreach (Control ctrl in c.Controls)
            {
                label6.Text = label6.Text + Environment.NewLine + ctrl.Name + ":" + ctrl.Parent.Name;
            }

        }
```

I can see that in LAbel6, it displays the name of the control as COM Legacy -11/30/2015 5:36:56 PM but I cant see the COM control. I have tried seting the visibility property of the COM control to true in the code (After the create control method) but still I cant see the control.

Please do advice on this.

**EDIT**

One thing to note is that I am able to see the programatically added panel (in the treeview after select event) but not the COM control which I have added to the panel.

**Update 1-Dec-2015**

I have removed the `CreateControl` line in the Tree view After Select and I am able to see the control.

But in the next lines I am opening a file into the control using the code, `axDynamic.Open(FileName, true);` In the button click event, the open file statement works fine. but in the after select event of th etree view, if I remove the `createcontrol`line, the control is visible, but the `axDynamic.Open(FileName, True)` throws an exception

> System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.InvalidActiveXStateException

I found after an amount of searching that this exception occurs if the `CreateControl` line is not used.

Hence I have to include the `CreateControl`line, but then with this line added the control is not visible.

Kindly Help me on this,

Comment: You are not asking that control to do anything.  So high odds that it just doesn't have anything useful to paint.  Change its BackColor property and try again.  And drop the panel, it is useless.

Comment: @HansPassant. Thanks for the comment. I am using the panel to have a width for the COM Control. (The Comp control when placed ona  container either takes the Dock.Fill or drwas in its own dimensions, which is not desirable for me). Regarding the Control not doing anything, the same code works in the button click event the problem is only in the tree view after select event.